# Golang on OpenShift, I can't find local module

Tags: go, openshift

I want to use an OpenShift test environment for my Golang applications.

I made a test application:

```
myproj/
------web.go
------/mylib/
-------------mylib.go
```

web.go is standard OpenShift file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "./mylib"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    bind := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", os.Getenv("HOST"), os.Getenv("PORT"))
    fmt.Printf("listening on %s...", bind)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(bind, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func hello(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    str := mylib.Lib();
    fmt.Fprintf(res, "hello, %s from %s", str, runtime.Version())
}
```

and I created "mylib"

```
package mylib

func Lib() string {
    return "world"
}
```

and when I run "go run web.go" everything works fine on my local computer. But when I try to upload this code to OpenShift I get the following error:

```
remote: -----> Using Go 1.1.2
remote: -----> Running: go get -tags openshift ./...
remote: can't load package: /var/lib/openshift/5354e6fd4382ec2dca000223/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/g/src/github.com/smarterclayton/goexample/web.go:8:2: local import "./mylib" in non-local package
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/5354e6fd4382ec2dca000223/go
```

What does this mean? Why can't Golang find this package? I can't write all code in one file. How should I write the application for OpenShift?

Comment: use absolue path  "myproj/mylib" instead

Comment: iam having serious issues with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is old but i had the same problem and it was difficult to find the solution, so i decided to ask in order to help who will run on the same problem.

The solution is very simple and can be found in readme of the go cartdrige repo on github: [github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-go-cart](https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-go-cart)

You have to create a file named ***.godir*** and put here the name of the main package of your server.
For example if you put ***myserver*** you can use:

```
package main
import "myserver/mylib"
func main() {
    mylib.DoStuff()
}
```

Basically when you push on openshift the repo is copied in the directory placed in ***.godir*** before the build

Comment: thanks, i will try this. i`m not using now openshift, but i need to know solution for future =)

Comment: im seriousl lost. i have my openshift repo. and I create another repo on m github account. In the .godir, itis point to the repo. example "github.com/myname/mrepo"  still doesnt seem to work?

Comment: you don't have to point to another server in .godir, just the main package name of your project. For example if in your local machine the project is in $GOPATH\src\project_name you have to put 'project_name' in .godir file